# Permissions associated with Android Application Shortcuts

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-security, android-shortcut

I'm trying to address some security review items on an Android app that I'm working on, and I'm looking at some "high severity" items related to shortcuts.

The security review is purely a static code analysis effort, and a number of the items the report has highlighted have been red herrings. I suspect that these ones are, too, but I'm looking for a second opinion.

The areas of code / config that have been flagged relate to setting up a shortcut:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context, MyShortcutActivity.class);
shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "My shortcut");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, getShortCutIconResource()));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
this.context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

The security report is complaining that I'm creating these intents with no permissions. But they're intents that are expected to invoked by the Android OS -- the OS creates the shortcut, and if the shortcut is clicked, the OS is launching MyShortcutActivity. So it doesn't feel to me like there's any special permission that's applicable.

The report is also flagging the definition of MyShortcutActivity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyShortcutActivity"
    ...
    android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

again with a complaint that it's lacking a permission. But since it can be launched by a shortcut, I don't really see what permission is applicable.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: So I'd already had the INSTALL_SHORTCUT permission in my manifest. Based on answers, here, I changed my code above, like so:

```
this.context.sendBroadcast(addIntent, Manifest.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT);
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: easypermission by Google is very recommended https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this permission to create a shortcut on the launcher menu :

[com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_SHORTCUT)

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. Any thoughts about permissions for the shortcut itself?

Comment: The Activity tag should not require to declare any extra permission if you declare the above permission in application tag

Answer (score 0):

Googling for a few seconds finds you the Android developer site with a large list of permissions.

```
INSTALL_SHORTCUT

Added in API level 19
String INSTALL_SHORTCUT
Allows an application to install a shortcut in Launcher.

Protection level: normal

Constant Value: "com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_SHORTCUT

Comment: Cool. I confess that when I tried combinations of "android", "permission", "shortcut", etc. I found myself sifting through a lot of unrelated pages. But your response helps.

Any insights into the other two parts of the question?

Comment: @bcholmes Sorry, I don't understand. What happens after you added the permission? Is it still getting flagged? You should mention the static analysis tool in the question.

Comment: Sadly, it's not a tool I'm running. Someone has sent my code to a third-party security audit company who've run their tool on it (I suspect that "their tool" is largely proprietary, in-house stuff). I just get a report available in a web portal. It's not a thing I can re-run on demand.